# Text Delta Determination (Hierarchical)

Tags: c#, algorithm, comparison, diff

I have a case which requires comparison (and diff determination) of two texts.

These are actually hierarchical configuration files and all sub items are indented in every level. Example :

File 1 :

```
conf_1
    conf_1_1
    conf_1_2
    conf_1_3
        conf_1_3_1
    conf_1_4
        conf_1_4_1
        conf_1_4_2
```

File 2 :

```
conf_1
    conf_1_1
    conf_1_2
    conf_1_3
        conf_1_3_1
        conf_1_3_2
    conf_1_4
        conf_1_4_1
        conf_1_4_2
    conf_1_5
```

The comparison between these two files should result as :

Result :

```
conf_1
    conf_1_3
        conf_1_3_2
    conf_1_5
```

Remarks :

- I'm only interested in plus delta (the additions in second file).
- Order of lines may change between two files, this shouldn't be
  interpreted as difference, as soon as hierarchy is preserved.

I have a solution :

"Flattening" the lines of each files ( e.g. conf_1 > conf_1_3 > conf_1_3_1 ), performing a brute-force comparison (comparing each line in File1 with each line in File2) and then re-indenting the different lines.

But I'm looking for more efficient solutions.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest populating a 2 hierarchical lists and processing them recursively.

Start with defining a simple class:

```
class Node
{
    public string Text;
    public List<Node> Children;
}
```

Here the `Text` is supposed to contain the text with indentation removed.

Then you would populate two node lists from your files, build another node list with differences, and write the result to another file. Something like this:

```
var nodes1 = ReadNodes(sourceFile1);
var nodes2 = ReadNodes(sourceFile2);
var diff = GetDiff(nodes1, nodes2);
if (diff.Count > 0)
{
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(diffFile))
        WriteDiff(sw, diff);
}
```

The used methods are:

```
static List<Node> ReadNodes(string fileName)
{
    // I'm leaving that part for you
}

static List<Node> GetDiff(List<Node> nodes1, List<Node> nodes2)
{
    if (nodes2 == null || nodes2.Count == 0) return null;
    if (nodes1 == null || nodes1.Count == 0) return nodes2;
    var map = nodes1.ToDictionary(n => n.Text);
    var diff = new List<Node>();
    foreach (var n2 in nodes2)
    {
        Node n1;
        if (!map.TryGetValue(n2.Text, out n1))
            diff.Add(n2);
        else
        {
            var childDiff = GetDiff(n1.Children, n2.Children);
            if (childDiff != null && childDiff.Count > 0)
                diff.Add(new Node { Text = n2.Text, Children = childDiff });
        }
    }
    return diff;
}


static void WriteDiff(TextWriter output, List<Node> nodes, int indent = 0)
{
    if (nodes == null) return;
    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < indent; i++)
            output.Write(' ');
        output.WriteLine(node.Text);
        WriteDiff(output, node.Children, indent + 4);
    }
}
```

Test using your example:

```
var nodes1 = new List<Node>
{
    new Node { Text = "conf_1", Children = new List<Node> {
        new Node { Text = "conf_1_1" },
        new Node { Text = "conf_1_2" },
        new Node { Text = "conf_1_3", Children = new List<Node> {
            new Node { Text = "conf_1_3_1" },
        } },
        new Node { Text = "conf_1_4", Children = new List<Node> {
            new Node { Text = "conf_1_4_1" },
            new Node { Text = "conf_1_4_2" },
        } },
    }},
};
var nodes2 = new List<Node>
{
    new Node { Text = "conf_1", Children = new List<Node> {
        new Node { Text = "conf_1_1" },
        new Node { Text = "conf_1_2" },
        new Node { Text = "conf_1_3", Children = new List<Node> {
            new Node { Text = "conf_1_3_1" },
            new Node { Text = "conf_1_3_2" },
        } },
        new Node { Text = "conf_1_4", Children = new List<Node> {
            new Node { Text = "conf_1_4_1" },
            new Node { Text = "conf_1_4_2" },
        } },
        new Node { Text = "conf_1_5" },
    }},
};
var diff = GetDiff(nodes1, nodes2);
if (diff.Count > 0)
{
    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        WriteDiff(sw, diff);
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ToString());
    }
}
```